# combining existing pages?

Tags: pages, html, ee, http, options

I am editing a webpage that is using EE. I am trying to make the table of contents smaller, is there a way for me to combine existing pages so that my table of contents will contain sub-categories? Using version 2.3.1

Comment: This needs much clarification ... what is your table of contents? How does it relate to "pages" or your categories?